# Native Camera with full functionalities on Flutter or React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

I'm currently selecting which framework to realize Android and iOS native camera functionalities for our client work. Due to the requirements and limitations of skills, I have to pick up either Flutter or React Native.

I have gone through the documents on both platforms, and I see there are some limitations on camera functionalities. (e.g. To my understanding, resolution presets are limited on Flutter, thumbnail image is not generated on React Native by default)

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera/camera

https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera

Is there any ways to fully activate the native camera functionalities on Flutter or React Native? If yes, how is it possible? (Maybe it's possible to implement the native functions with Kotlin or Swift inside Flutter or React Native source?)

This is my first project for mobile development, so apologies for the lack of understanding both platforms' technologies.
My concern is "how Flutter or React Native camera app would be different from the native code app". Shooting speed, Burst mode, Zooming function, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter you can use [Platform Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) as you said to interract with native code.

React native have a similar ability for [Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) which provides a similar functionality.

In terms of comparing the two languages Flutter uses Dart as the language and react native uses Javascript, if you are planning on using something more familiar that could also be a consideration. [Here](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-what-to-choose-in-2021#f2) is a comparison chart showing differences between the two.